# Which field matched query in multi_match search in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have  query with multi_match in Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "luk",
      "fields": [
        "xml_string.autocomplete",
        "state"
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "fields": [
    "xml_string",
    "state"
  ]
}
```

It works great, result returns expected value:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.41179964,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "documents",
        "_type": "document",
        "_id": "11",
        "_score": 0.41179964,
        "fields": {
          "xml_string": "Lukas bla bla bla",
          "state": "new"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've searched a lot, but I am not able to find out which field matched the query(if it was xml_string OR state)

Answer (score 12):

I have found solution: I have used highlight feature and it's working great

This is how my curl looks like:

```
 curl -X GET 'http://xxxxx.com:9200/documents/document/_search?load=false&size=10&pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "123",
            "fields": ["some_field", "another_field"]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "some_field": {},
            "another_field": {}
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "fields": ["field","another_field"]
}'
```

Comment: Perfect my friend... It uses when matched field require to process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no feature for telling you which field has matched the query.

But you can use the explain feature for debugging your query. You only have to add to your query the pamameter `&explain=true`. With this parameter you will see an explanation for each field of why it is in the result set and you will guess which field matched the query.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i was afraid that someone would write this kind of answer :)
I am looking for some way, to search over multiple fields, and know which field returned value. It's for autocomplete. In later versions, it should return invoice number, or supplier name...

Comment: I have found solution, I have added it as new answer